# dash dcc.Uploader not working in multipage app

Tags: plotly-dash

0

I have a multi-page dash app for generating custom dashboards based on user submission. I'm trying to create a secondary page for uploading files. The problem is that the dcc.Upload or the callback function does not produce the expected behavior, that is: a html.Div that shows the uploaded data.

This is my secondary page, organized in tabs:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_mantine_components as dmc
from dash import dash_table
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import os
import unicodedata
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import quote as urlquote
import sqlite3
from dash_iconify import DashIconify
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
from app import app

def layout():
    return [
        dmc.Tabs(
            [
                dmc.TabsList(
                    [
                        dmc.Tab("Import", value="import"),
                        dmc.Tab("Connect BD", value="connectbd"),
                        dmc.Tab("Explore", value="explore"),
                    ]
                ),
                dmc.TabsPanel(
                    html.Div([
                        dcc.Upload(
                            id='upload-data',
                            children=html.Div([
                                'Drag and Drop or ',
                                html.A('Select Files')
                            ]),
                            style={
                                'width': '100%',
                                'height': '260px',
                                'lineHeight': '60px',
                                'borderWidth': '1px',
                                #'borderStyle': 'dashed',
                                'background' : '#f8f9fa',
                                'borderRadius': '5px',
                                'textAlign': 'center',
                                'margin': '10px'
                            },
                            # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
                            multiple=True,                            
                        ),
                        html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
                    ]),
                    value="import"),
                dmc.TabsPanel("Settings tab content", value="connectbd"),
                dmc.TabsPanel("Settings tab content", value="explore"),
            ],
            #color="black",
            orientation="horizontal",
        )
    ]

def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):

    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
        html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

        dash_table.DataTable(
            df.to_dict('records'),
            [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
        ),

        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])

@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('upload-data', 'last_modified'))
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children
```

**Solution attempts:** the example of the dcc.Upload is in the documentation , but I use it inside a tab inside a secondary page that is called with the layout function in the app.py. The example is working correctly when is run as it is implemented in the documentation, but I can´t adapt it to my specific use case. I think the problem is near the callback or in the function that outputs the table.

I´m a newbie in dash. Thanks in advance for any help.

Expted: html.Div with uploaded data.